# Append String to Array/Save in Parse - Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

What I am doing is calling a "Block Group" action from an UIAlertController.  That UIAlertAction triggers a check to see if you are the groupProfile, then assigns my Parse column "Blocked" to the blockedGroups array.  I then declare a variable to collect the current user's objectID, this is what I want to append to my array each time the Block Group button is pressed.

The array is getting correctly added as I can see it print in the log, but I am unable to see it in the Parse backend.  The good thing is all of the other users are undefined until I hit the "Block Group" function on them, and then it turns to [ ] but not populated with the objectIDs.  Am I not saving it correctly?

[image][image]

(the three populated with [ ] are working, I have manually hit Block Group on, but not populating with objectIDs.)

```
   var groupProfile: PFObject?
   var blockedGroups : [String] = []

   let blockAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Block Group", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        if groupProfile != nil {
            groupProfile!["Blocked"] = self.blockedGroups
            let blockID = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)! as String
            self.blockedGroups.append(blockID)
            var blockID2 = self.blockedGroups.append(blockID)
            groupProfile!["Blocked"] = blockID2
            print("Array: \(self.blockedGroups)")
        } else {
    }
            groupProfile!.saveInBackground()
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, you may wish to use `guard let groupProfile = groupProfile else { return }` to exit the closure early. Then paste all the code inside the `if` underneath that. Using this, you don't need exclamation points after `groupProfile`.

Comment: I have the `groupProfile` variable declared in the appDelegate. I just declared it here for the example's purpose.  Thank you for the info.

Comment: Does more info need to be posted in order to better understand?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you declare the class where you want to save `groupProfile` ?

In order to save an object you have to do :

```
var groupProfile = PFObject(className: "CLASSNAME")
    groupProfile["Blocked"] = blockID2
    groupProfile.saveInBackground()
```

Also, from your code, you are doing 
`groupProfile!["Blocked"] = self.blockedGroups` and
`groupProfile!["Blocked"] = blockID2` in the same block, which is useless.